# employee's job to calculate salary using java

Tags: java

There's something missing in the codes.. if I choose part time(no.1), it must only show hourly rate and hours worked to compute for income.. but the overtime pay, overtime hours and overtime rate keeps on showing when they are supposed to come out if I choose (no.2):

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
//author: Misty Stewart

     public class salary{
            static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
              public static void main (String[]args)  { 

              String name = "";
              int kindOfEmployee;
              int overtimePay = 0;
              int HRate = 0;
              int HWorked = 0;
              int regularPay = 0;
              int overtimeRate = 0;
              int overtimeHours = 0;
              int Income = 0;

              Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

              System.out.println("Enter Name of the employee:");
              name = console.next ();
            System.out.println("1]Part-time Employee");
            System.out.println("2]Full-time Employee");
            System.out.println("Choose what kind of employee?");
            kindOfEmployee=console.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Hourly Rate:");
              HRate = input.nextInt();
              System.out.println("Hours Worked:");
              HWorked = input.nextInt();
              System.out.println("Regular Pay:");
              regularPay = input.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Overtime Rate:");
              overtimeRate = input.nextInt();
              System.out.println("Overtime Hours:");    
              overtimeHours = input.nextInt();   
              overtimePay = overtimeRate*overtimeHours;

              System.out.println("Name of the employee: "+name);
              System.out.println("Income: "+Income);

              if (kindOfEmployee == 1){
                  Income = HRate*HWorked;            
                       }
              if (kindOfEmployee == 2){
                   Income = regularPay+overtimePay;     
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what will i do to stop it from showing?

Comment: part time no.1 and no.2 that i said above the codes refers to the kindOfEmplyee

Comment: You're printing the income before you run it through the logic.

Comment: thanks..i got it. but i still have a problem.. if i choose part time(no.1), it must only show hourly rate and hours worked to compute for income.. but the overtime pay , overtime hours and overtime rate keeps on showing when they are supposed to come out if i choose (no.2)

Comment: You're printing them all the time. You need to add logic saying if you choose #1, only print this, if no. 2, print that.

Comment: pls. give me an example if you don't mind sir...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (kindOfEmployee == 2) {
    System.out.println("Overtime Rate:");
    overtimeRate = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Overtime Hours:");    
    overtimeHours = input.nextInt();   
    overtimePay = overtimeRate*overtimeHours;
}
```